# Updating Constants in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, constants

Is there a way to update constants in ARM assembly and do something like this:

```
.equ numbers, 0
infloop:
    mov r1, #numbers
    add r1, r1, #1
    str numbers [r1]
    b infloop
```

Comment: If you could change them, they wouldn't be constants.

Comment: updated constant is called 'variable'. wished `str numbers [r1]` in ARM is `mov r2, #numbers; str r2, [r1]`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not like you have written.  The code `mov r1,#numbers` will be encoded in the machine instruction.  If you want to change 'numbers', you would have to update the machine opcodes.  This is 'self modifying code' and is not recommended.  If you instead do `mov r1,=number`, there are more options.  But really this is just like `ldr r1,[rx]` and `str r1,[rx]`.  Ie, just use memory as the ARM architechure is load/store.

Comment: Think of `.equ` as something like C `#define` or `static const int`.  Use something else if you want to modify it, like some static storage somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

No. The assembler replaces `numbers` with 0 before the code is ever executed.